# Catch result of process from exe (right click context)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, registry, right-click

I wrote following reg file inorder to delete files/folders securely.

Cmd working as expected. But sometimes I would like to see result of it (I do not want to disappare of cmd window)

How can I pause / wait / stop before windows disappared

"D:\Desktop\_NotUse\SDelete\sdelete.exe -s -p 5 \"%1\"" **/pause** did not work.

Here is my registry file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\SDelete]
@="Secure Delete File"
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-89"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\SDelete\Command]
@="D:\\Desktop\\_NotUse\\SDelete\\sdelete.exe -p 5 \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\SDelete Directory]
@="Secure Delete Folder"
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-89"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\SDelete Directory\command]
@="D:\\Desktop\\_NotUse\\SDelete\\sdelete.exe -s -p 5 \"%1\""
```

Comment: Are there any way to have confirmation promt?

Comment: `@="D:\\Desktop\\_NotUse\\SDelete\\sdelete.exe -p 5 \"%1\" & pause"` or something alike.

Comment: @JosefZ I tried `@="D:\\Desktop\\_NotUse\\SDelete\\sdelete.exe -p 5 \"%1\" && pause"` both with single & and double but no luck

Comment: What is the `sdelete.exe`? A command-line utility? Try ` ^& pause`

Comment: @JosefZ I tried `@="D:\\Desktop\\_NotUse\\SDelete\\sdelete.exe -p 5 \"%1\" ^& pause"` it did not work either.

Comment: Yes SDelete is a command line utility from microsoft

Comment: Error :
no files/folders found that match &
no files/folders found that match pause

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. See @trigger's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sdelete doesn't have a pause command. You'll need to run it with a program that doesn't exit so console stays open.

See `cmd /?`

eg

```
cmd /k forfiles
```

or

```
cmd /c forfiles & pause
```

Comment: I need some help to run input, `forfiles /p D:\Desktop\_NotUse\SDelete\ /c "sdelete.exe -p 5 "%1"" & pause` I could not run this also.

Comment: Forfiles is an EXAMPLE. Sdelete is not part of windows so examples are given with Window's files SO THEY WORK no matter what your system configuration.

Comment: I found solution thank you for your help here is the solution if someone needs `cmd /k D:\Desktop\_NotUse\SDelete\sdelete.exe -s -p 5 "%1" & pause & exit`